# What is the question mark in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking at a new codebase right now and I've never encountered this before. Is it just checking for whether or not `items.length > 0`?

```
<div className={cn('input-dropdown-wrap', 
    { 'input-dropdown-wrap--active': isActive && items?.length })
}>
```

Comment: is it JS or TypeScript?

Comment: It's `Optional chaining` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: Well do you remember errors like `can read property 'prop1' of undefined`, so to avoid these errors we can manually check the object is defined & its property 'prop1' can be read or you can use this `?.` to just do that for you.